# Backbone Model urlroot

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

These are the path url's that my server has:

```
GET /watchlists
GET /watchlists/:id
POST /watchlists // Create a new watchlists
PUT /watchlists/:id // Change attributes of watchlists (Like name)
POST /watchlists/:id/movies // Add a movie
DELETE /watchlists/:id/movies/:trackId //  Delete a movie by the trackid
DELETE /watchlists/:id // Delete the watchlists by is ID
```

Here is my model:

```
var WatchlistModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/watchlists',
});
```

I want to know how to do the 'add a movie' with this url:

```
/watchlists/:id/movies
```

and the delete call:

```
/watchlists/:id/movies/:trackId
```

What are the best pratices for that?

Comment: You need to create a Backbone model for your movies, and create an urlRoot method in it to to retrieve the id of the watchlist including it.

Comment: I'm not sure to figure out this.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a `Movies` collection as a child of each `WatchlistModel` model, give it a reference of its parent and use that reference to build its `url`.

Assuming the reference to the parent is stored in a `watchlist` attribute, something like

```
var Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
       return _.result(this.watchlist, 'url') + '/movies';
    }
});

var WatchlistModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/watchlists',
    initialize: function() {
        this.movies = new Movies();
        this.movies.watchlist = this;
    }
});
```

You would create a new movie like this:

```
var lst = new WatchlistModel({id: 1});
var newmovie = lst.movies.create();
```

Comment: shouldn't be 
         return _.result(this.watchlist, 'url') + '/movies'

? otherwise you get the same url as the parent collection